# typescript imported JSON object undefined

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, webpack

I'm importing a JS file into a Typescript file using `import * as main from './main';`, but when i try to access `main.todos`, which is assigned with `todos = JSON.parse(data);` inside main.js - (data) being some JSON i've recieved from a server. However, when i log the variable, `console.log(main.todos);` the console tells me it is undefined, but when i log the entire `main` object, i can see the data inside `main.todos`, shown below.

[image]

I'm also using webpack and have been advised that instead of this method i could use ProvidePlugin, but from relevant documentation i don't understand how to implement this for my main.js

Comment: async load of jason?

Comment: I haven't used TS much, but shouldn't you use `this.todos = JSON.parse(data)` to make it accessible like you want ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón yes, the load is async. It would make sense for that to be the issue, how is it resolvable?

Comment: i think, to capture this object value, first you must confirm  was loaded. So using the method to load data, sure there is a callback, promise or any that tell this

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón i'm using a function which returns a promise, then handles the retrieved object using .then() - i considered exporting the retrieval function but the app shouldn't have to load the data multiple times if avoidable

Comment: and in this promise, can you make a console output,  to saw if is ok loaded. ( no need to load every time, store it into a value , and when is loaded then make your code, and wait your code untill is loaded)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón it's loaded fine, i'm using it in the main js file to inject info to the page (which wouldnt work if it wasnt loaded). However, i need to pass the value to this file and i believe the import is not recognising it properly. See in the image in the original question post that it says object{todos:undefined}, but when i open up the object in console it shows that the data is there.